# IsLoading with multi call functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question that is a bit special because I have many ideas but i search "THE OWN SOLUTION" to answer my needs.
Indeed on my page when I load an element, I display a loader like this:

```
 return (
      {isLoading && (<CircularProgress className="circularProgress" size={40} />)}
  );
```

My problem is that I use one or more functions that call on my back-end and that allow me to display elements on my page.
However, by doing like the example below, my loader is OFF as soon as the first call is finished.

example :

```
const function1 = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    route.getSomething1()
     .then(() => {
     }).finally(() => {
       setIsLoading(false);
     });
}
const function2 = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    route.getSomething2()
     .then(() => {
     }).finally(() => {
       setIsLoading(false);
     });
}
```

I thought about making a promise, however sometimes I will call only 1 function and sometimes 5 functions at the same time.
It will depend on the actions the user performs on the interface.

How I could solve my problem in the cleanest way, because yes I could do multiple isLoading variables for each function, however I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: In my opinion, just use multiple loading, because all the function is executed at the same time

Comment: it depends on your software, we give you the perfect answer without knowing how exactly the code is used .

Comment: I just want to put a loading mask when a back call is made. Only today it stops even before all functions are finished. Unless I use multiple variables from IsLoading1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: can you maybe show us the complete component? :)

Comment: Rather than a boolean you can make isLoading an integer and increment it every time you make an API call and decrement it when the API call is finished. Now for your loader, you can use the condition (isLoading > 0  && ...)

Comment: @ArpitParmar I hadn't thought about it, but I really like the idea! thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments we can do the following:

API Calls:

```
const function1 = () => {
    setIsLoading(prevValue => ++prevValue);
    route.getSomething1()
     .then(() => {
     }).finally(() => {
       setIsLoading(prevValue => --prevValue);
     });
}
const function2 = () => {
    setIsLoading(prevValue => ++prevValue);
    route.getSomething2()
     .then(() => {
     }).finally(() => {
       setIsLoading(prevValue => --prevValue);
     });
}
```

Loader Condition:

```
return {isLoading > 0 && (<CircularProgress className="circularProgress" size={40} />)};
```

Comment: It's better to change the variable name as well, variable with prefix `is` tends to be used as boolean. Just a suggestion to improve the readability.

Comment: Would love to know the suggestions regarding the name we can use in place of isLoading. Choosing a variable name is tough man haha